# Create folder from Google Sheet then retrieve the corresponding folderId and dateCreated() using google scripts

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help, please...seems easy but I am stuck. I found this code and change it a bit to create a folder from google sheets then I would like to retrieve the corresponding folderId and dateCreated. I am able to create the test folder but it is not looping through the rows and not printing the folderId and dateCreated values. I am testing out two new folders to be created in Google Drive.

My Spreadsheet contains the following:

```
(A) New Parent Folder
(A2) New folder1
(A3) New folder2
(B) Folder Id - print the parent folderId
(B2) Print New folder1 folderId
(B3) Print New folder2 folderId
(C) Date Created - print the creation date
(C2) Print New folder1 dateCreated
(C3) Print New folder2 dateCreated
(D) Root Folder
(D2) Root Folder URL
```

// MakeFolders

```
function create(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Make Folders');  
  var project = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var lastColumn = 4;

  var projectName = project[0][0];
  var parentId = project [0][1];
  var date = project [0][2];
  var rootFolder = project [0][3]; 

  for (i=0; i<projectName.length ; i++){
  if (projectName == '') {
    return false;
  } else {
      var rootURL = sheet.getRange('D2').getValue();
      var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootURL).createFolder(projectName);
      var name = newFolder.getName(); // substring(7);
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXX').makeCopy(newFolder);
    }
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(newFolder.getId());
  sheet.getRange(2,3).setValue(newFolder.getDateCreated());
}
}
```

The script only loops through the A2 and keeps creating the same folder. perhaps my looping was incorrect...I would like the code to be able to run through the ColumnA (if there is a new data) and print the folderId and creation date into google sheet.

TIA for your help.

---

I have updated my code but the first folder I created did not pull and post the 1st folder info but it did for the second folder. How do I fix this? Am I missing something?

```
   function createFolders(){
      var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX")
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Make Folders');
      var project = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //data

      for (i=0; i<project.length-1; i++){
        var root = project [i][0];
        var folderName = project[i][1];
        var id = project[i][2];
        var datec = project[i][3];

         var rootid = ss.getRange('A2').getValue();  //user enters the root folder id
         var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootid).createFolder(project[i][0]);
      }
      sheet.getRange(i+1,3,1,2).setValues([ [newFolder.getId(), newFolder.getDateCreated()] ]);                        
    }
```

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Your loop is indeed incorrect. You will need to use the iterator `i` and your sheet data `project`. Review tutorials on JavaScript loops.

Comment: Regarding your recent edit, you still have some legacy logic that needs removing (`rootid` vs `root`), and your write statement uses the iterator but is outside the loop. While it is best to do writes outside the loop (batch operations), you must then create the object being written inside the loop (with each in-memory row of data). Review the apps script "best practices" page for some examples that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to create the test folder but it is not looping through the rows and not printing the folderId and dateCreated values.

You should spend sometime learning about looping through 2D arrays on JavaScrip because your script is using getValues() and it returns a 2D array. In the meantime instead of

```
for (i=0; i<projectName.length ; i++){
```

try

```
for (i=0; i<project.length - 1 ; i++){
```

and instead of

```
var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootURL).createFolder(projectName);
```

try

```
var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootURL).createFolder(project[i][0]);
```

Comment: That's *one* of OP's issues... the biggest is that `i` is not even used.